# Does the number of mono-behavior scripts that don't use update or fixed update affect performance?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a shooter project and I have implemented a weapon switch mechanic, currently I only use one script that's called Gun and it performs shoot, reload, etc... and while switching the weapons I cache the data of the previous weapons and then use the cached data of the weapon that we switched to, now this is a bit messy, now I want to have a Gun script for each weapon and that would be a lot of instances of the Gun script, but the Gun script doesn't use unity's update function, so does it still affect performance?

Comment: Only monbehaviours on instantiated gameobjects count.

Comment: Every new cached gun object will add up to the memory (RAM) and that will add up for performance decrease little by little.

So, practically you should use object pooling if a lot of guns instance will be needed but only some of them will be active or enabled at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every single object created affects your program performance somehow. So the short answer is YES.

However, it is a really big question if it will affect the performance of your game significantly enough to cause lags or some other not wanted side effects.

I suggest not thinking about it right now until you have real problems. To be more precise - do not think about it hard and do not try to optimize early something that can be easily optimized later.

For example, in your case with weapons you can use object pooling or make it not MonoBehaviour. Both variants can be implemented later in case of need.

Just look into the profiler from time to time to catch potential issues early. It should be enough for most cases.